# Batch increase drone imagery altitude by editing EXIF GPS information

Tags: qgis, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, exif, batch, qgis-modeler

I have around 3.600 drone images covering an area of around 2 x 4 KMs. The images were recorded using two drones. For some reason the images from one of the drones is off by around 15 meters in the z-axis. This could be space weather, drone specifications etc.

The software I am using in this case is Pix4D. It produces a fine orthophoto. The point cloud represents the difference in altitude well. This means the 3D-model shows up with an unsavory step up where the images from the two drones meet.
[image]

There might be several ways to fix this. One of them is to adjust the exif altitude (GPSAltitude) of the images from one of the drones.

I thus need to systematically subtract 15 meters from the EXIF information for all images from one of the drones. Are there any GIS tools which could help me out here, or should I script it using Python?

Comment: PyExifTool  is the python version of ExifTool (perl) https://exiftool.org/ https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/ check if your image format is supported.

Comment: I needed to do something similar last year: overwrite the GPSAltitude tag by adding a constant to the value of the RelativeAltitude tag. I made a [small script in bash](https://github.com/gabriel-de-luca/cambiar_altura) (documented in Spanish), which makes use of exiftool and could help you as a base.

Comment: If you just want to change all the altitudes to a single value you can do it inside the pix4d software. Just go to Image Properties Editor and right click on a altitude value then edit all attributes and change the value.